# ASP.NET MVC 3 JSONP: Does this work with JsonValueProviderFactory?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jsonp, model-binding

Phil Haack has an excellent [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx) on how to use JSON, data binding, and data validation.

Enter the browser's "same origin policy security restriction." and JSONP where you use $.getJSON() to retrieve the content.

Is there a built in MVC 3 way to do this, or do I need to follow the advice of [posts like this](http://abcoder.com/javascript/jquery/jsonp-first-timer/)?  Can you post content? I ask because my colleague implemented a JsonPfilterAttribute among other things to make this work.  It's obviously preferred to avoid that if something already exists in MVC 3.

**Edit:**

**Summary: everything works with the exception of accessing a `POST` variable, i.e., how do I access the `POST` variable in the context?** (comment marking it in the last section of code)

I elected to use this format to call the server:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "GetMyDataJSONP",
    data: {},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "randomFunctionName"
});
```

Which produces this response:

```
randomFunctionName([{"firstField":"111","secondField":"222"}]);
```

And all this works very well if I use a `GET`.  However, I still cannot get this to work as a `POST`.  Here's the original code posted by Nathan Bridgewater [here](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/07/cross-domain-jsonp-using-asp-net-mvc-and-jquery/).  This line doesn't find the POST data:

```
context.HttpContext.Request["callback"];
```

Either I should be accessing `Form` in some way, or the MVC data validators are stripping out the POST variables.

**How should `context.HttpContext.Request["callback"];` be written to access the `POST` variable or is MVC stripping out these values for some reason?**

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{   public class JsonpResult : ActionResult
    {   public JsonpResult() {}

        public Encoding ContentEncoding { get; set; }
        public string ContentType { get; set; }
        public object Data { get; set; }
        public string JsonCallback { get; set; }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {   if (context == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

            this.JsonCallback = context.HttpContext.Request["jsoncallback"];

            // This is the line I need to alter to find the form variable:

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.JsonCallback))
                this.JsonCallback = context.HttpContext.Request["callback"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.JsonCallback))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(
                    "JsonCallback required for JSONP response.");

            HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType))
               response.ContentType = ContentType;
            else
               response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

            if (ContentEncoding != null)
                response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;

            if (Data != null)
            {   JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                response.Write(string.Format("{0}({1});", this.JsonCallback,
                    serializer.Serialize(Data)));
    }   }   }

    //extension methods for the controller to allow jsonp.
    public static class ContollerExtensions
    {
        public static JsonpResult Jsonp(this Controller controller, 
               object data)
        {
            JsonpResult result = new JsonpResult();
            result.Data = data;
            result.ExecuteResult(controller.ControllerContext);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As far as receiving a JSON string and binding it to a model is concerned the `JsonValueProviderFactory` does this job out of the box in ASP.NET MVC 3. But there is nothing built-in for outputting JSONP. You could write a custom `JsonpResult`:

```
public class JsonpResult : JsonResult
{
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        string jsoncallback = (context.RouteData.Values["jsoncallback"] as string) ?? request["jsoncallback"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsoncallback))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(base.ContentType))
            {
                base.ContentType = "application/x-javascript";
            }
            response.Write(string.Format("{0}(", jsoncallback));
        }
        base.ExecuteResult(context);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsoncallback))
        {
            response.Write(")");
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your controller action:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    return new JsonpResult
    {
        Data = new { Prop1 = "value1", Prop2 = "value2" },
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    };
}
```

which could be consumed from another domain with [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

```
$.getJSON('http://example.com/home/foo?jsoncallback=?', function(data) {
    alert(data.Prop1);
});
```

Comment: I edited the question to reflect your answer (nice answer), just need one more piece working.

Comment: @Dr. Zim, `JSONP` works only with GET requests as implemented by jQuery. There is no magic here, jQuery simply injects a `<script>` tag into the DOM of the hosting page pointing to the remote server and as you know a `<script>` tag can only send a GET request to this remote resource. So don't even try `$.ajax({ type: 'POST' });`, with JSONP, that's never gonna work. In fact you could make it work by using hidden iframe and hidden forms but that's not what jQuery uses to implement JSONP.

Comment: But to answer your question in general `context.HttpContext.Request["jsoncallback"];` will also look into the POSTed values if they are present.

Comment: Fantastic.  I would have been pursuing it to the end without knowing that.

Comment: I was thinking on using an ActionFilterAttribute but I think that your derived class is a much better solution, thanks.