# JSONPCallback function steps into error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I trying to call cross domain call from jquery. The functions steps into error section with the error message, "alertResponse was not called". I am using Jquery version "jquery-1.6.2" and I am able to view the result of action checkSession in browser using "http://localhost:123/Home/CheckSession". Also in the visual studio debugger, the browser is loaded with the actual result returned from above url. But I am unable to get the value from the jquery.

Please find the Jquery code below:
The Jquery code is in different domain - http://localhost:7451/TestPage.aspx

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
           SetActionItemCount();
         });
         function SetActionItemCount() {
               var URL = "http://localhost:123/Home/CheckSession";
                function alertResponse(data, status) {
                     alert("data: " + data + ", status: " + status);
                     }
                 $.ajax({
                 url: URL,
                  dataType: 'jsonp',
                  jsonp: 'callback',
                  jsonpCallback: 'alertResponse',
                  success: function (jsonp) {
                            alert(jsonp);
                            },
                  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                                alert("error");
                            }
                  });
              }
```

### Server side MVC action method - this code is in "http://localhost:123/Home/CheckSession"

```
    public JsonResult CheckSession()
    {
        string status = string.Empty;
        status = "test data";               
        return Json(new { status },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I am not sure what is that I am missing here.
Also, when I run the jquery with debugger attached to localhost:32088, I get the debugger in checksession action method and it does return the value.
But I am unable to get the value in jquery.

The output that I receive when I try the url "http://localhost:123/Home/CheckSession" in browser is
{"status":"test data"}

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's some confusion here:

- `jsonpCallback` is *not* supposed to supply a named function to act as the success callback. It's only specifying the internal *name* of the callback function jQuery will use to handle the JSON response - the actual *code* for that function is specified by the `success` parameter. As far as I know, the main reason to use this is to support better client-side caching - something you probably don't want in a `CheckSession` script. So I would drop `jsonCallback` altogether and put your `alertResponse` code in the `success` function.
- Your server-side script needs to wrap the JSON response in the code `<callbackName>(...);`, where `<callbackName>` is the name of the function supplied in the request URL, and `...` is your JSON. So if the request is `/Home/CheckSession?callback=alertResponse`, your response should look like `alertResponse(<JSON>);`. It looks like you're just sending back the JSON with no wrapper code.
- `jsonp: 'callback'` is unnecessary (it's the default).

Comment: I am not sure on how to wrap the response in the server code.Can you please modify my piece of code, that would be great help.

Comment: Sadly, I don't know asp.net, so I can't rewrite that code. It's just string concatenation - you'd need to get the value of the "callback" parameter, then return `callbackName + "(" + json + ");"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return JSONP from your server, not JSON. Take a look at the [following blog post](http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/entry-EnablingJSONPcallsonASPNETMVC.aspx) which illustrates how you can write a custom `JsonpResult` action result to use in your controller action. And here's a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4797071/29407).

Comment: OK. Thanks. I will look into this post and get back to you I need any clarification.